# Set container environment variables while creating a deployment with kubectl create

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

We can create a deployment with:

```
kubectl create deployment nginx-deployment --image=nginx
```

How can we pass an environment variable, say, `key=value`, for container while creating a deployment using `kubectl`?

Additionally, can we also use `configmap` or `secret` values as environment variables?

Answer (score 2):

`kubectl run nginx-pod --generator=run-pod/v1 --image=nginx --env="key1=value1" --env="key2=value2"...`

Reference - [`run`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run).

Answer (score 1):

> **`kubectl create deployment`** command does not have option to pass environment variable as a flag on the imperative command .. possible available flags on create deployment command are as below (***listed by autocomplete on on kubectl cli***)

```
   $ kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx --
--add-dir-header               --client-certificate=          --insecure-skip-tls-verify     --log-flush-frequency=         --profile-output=              --token
--allow-missing-template-keys  --client-key                   --kubeconfig                   --logtostderr                  --request-timeout              --token=
--alsologtostderr              --client-key=                  --kubeconfig=                  --match-server-version         --request-timeout=             --user
--as                           --cluster                      --log-backtrace-at             --namespace                    --save-config                  --user=
--as=                          --cluster=                     --log-backtrace-at=            --namespace=                   --server                       --username
--as-group                     --context                      --log-dir                      --output                       --server=                      --username=
--as-group=                    --context=                     --log-dir=                     --output=                      --skip-headers                 --v
--cache-dir                    --dry-run                      --log-file                     --password                     --skip-log-headers             --v=
--cache-dir=                   --generator                    --log-file=                    --password=                    --stderrthreshold              --validate
--certificate-authority        --generator=                   --log-file-max-size            --profile                      --stderrthreshold=             --vmodule
--certificate-authority=       --image                        --log-file-max-size=           --profile=                     --template                     --vmodule=
--client-certificate           --image=                       --log-flush-frequency          --profile-output               --template=
```

> Alternately **`kubectl run`** command **can be used to create a deployment** which will allow you to pass env flag on the imperative command , refer below example

```
 $ kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --env="TEST"="/var/tmp"
kubectl run --generator=deployment/apps.v1 is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 or kubectl create instead.
deployment.apps/nginx created
```

Now ***to check the env variable has been correctly set you can connect to the POD and display the env variables to verify*** it

Connect

```
$ kubectl exec -it nginx /bin/bash
```

**List env variables on the pod**

```
root@nginx:/# env | grep -i test
TEST=/var/tmp
```

Refer official doc example for second part of your question [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

When creating a pod you can specify the environment variables using the `--env` option eg.

```
kubectl run nginx-pod --restart Never --image=nginx --env=key1=value1,key2=value2
```

Checkout [kubectl run](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run) documentation

However, you cannot do this with [kubectl create deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-deployment-em-). I'll recommend you use a declarative manifest instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility as other community members pointed to pass a variable to a pod but I would advise you to use a declarative approach to creating objects in Kubernetes. [Why would I?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/)

There is a nice [comic](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/imperative-vs-declarative-kubernetes-management-a-digitalocean-comic) explaining differences between imperative and declarative approach.

Below are examples to:

- Create a basic NGINX deployment
- Create a `Configmap` and `Secret` in a declarative approach
- Apply above `Configmap` and `Secret` to already created NGINX deployment

### Create a basic NGINX deployment

Create a `YAML` definition of NGINX similar to this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 3 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Apply it by running `$ kubectl apply -f FILE_NAME.yaml`

### Create a basic `ConfigMap`

Create a YAML definition of `ConfigMap` similar to this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-for-nginx
data:
  port: "12345"
```

Apply it by running `$ kubectl apply -f FILE_NAME.yaml`

### Create a basic `Secret`

Create a YAML definition of `Secret` similar to this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: password-for-nginx
type: Opaque
data:
  password: c3VwZXJoYXJkcGFzc3dvcmQK
```

Take a specific look at:

```
  password: c3VwZXJoYXJkcGFzc3dvcmQK
```

**This password is base64 encoded**.

To create this password invoke command from your terminal:
`$ echo "YOUR_PASSWORD" | base64`

Paste the output to the `YAML` definition and apply it with:
`$ kubectl apply -f FILE_NAME`.

### Apply above `Configmap` and `Secret` to already created NGINX deployment

You can edit your previously created NGINX deployment and add the part responsible for adding the `ConfigMap` and `Secret` to be available as environmental variables:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        env:
        - name: NGINX_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: password-for-nginx
              key: password
        - name: NGINX_PORT
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: config-for-nginx
              key: port
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Please take a specific look on below part which will add the environmental variables to created pods as `NGINX_PASSWORD` and `NGINX_PORT`:

```
        env:
        - name: NGINX_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: password-for-nginx
              key: password
        - name: NGINX_PORT
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: config-for-nginx
              key: port
```

The `secretKeyRef` is reference to created `Secret` and the `configMapKeyRef` is the reference for created `ConfigMap`.

Apply it by running `$ kubectl apply -f FILE_NAME.yaml` once more.

**It will terminate old pods and create new one with new configuration.**

To check if environmental variables are configured correctly  invoke below commands:

- `$ kubectl get pods`
- `$ kubectl exec -it NAME_OF_THE_POD -- /bin/bash`
- `$ echo $NGINX_PORT`
- `$ echo $NGINX_PASSWORD`

You should see the variables from `ConfigMap` and `Secret` accordingly.